# Multiple bean referring to the same class?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

In Spring config file, I have created two bean for the same class i.e.

```
<bean id="emp1" class="Employee">
    <property name="age" value="10"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="emp2" class="Employee">
    <property name="age" value="15"></property>
</bean>
```

and scope for both is by default 'singleton' but when I print Employee object its showing two different objects. How is this possible? I mean 
If the bean scope is singleton then how it's creating two different objects ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should return 2 employees.
Singleton has a slightly different meaning in spring - it's not about guaranteeing 1 instance per class.
It just means every time you call "context.getBean("emp1")" you'll get the same object, as opposed to "prototype" which means getting a different instance each time to call context.getBean("emp1")

try this

```
Object x1=context.getBean("emp1");
Object x2=context.getBean("emp1");
```

If "emp1" is singleton you'll get the same reference. If prototype you'll get two separate instances.